# Returning a value if three columns match in excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

I have two excel sheets where I need to match three values to return a fourth. The similar columns are month, agent, and subdomain. The fourth column is called difference.

Comment: You could CONCATENATE those cells in both sheets and then use a VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Concatenate would work, as per @MakeCents suggestion, but if you don't want a helper column, `SUMPRODUCT` would work.

example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12="d"),--(B2:B12="S"),--(C2:C12="Apr"),D2:D12)
```

would search range A2:A12 for "d", B2:B12 for "S" and C2:C12 for "Apr", and return the value fom D2:D12 that corresponds to where all 3 are true. If multiple lines match, it will add the value in D2:D12 for all matching rows.

The `--` is used to change the True/False results into 0 and 1 for use in multiplication

Limitations of `SUMPRODUCT`

- Recommended to specify the range explicitly; it will be slower with just
  column references
  (**A1:A4000** is ok, **A:A** is not)
- It will return an error if ***any*** of the values are errors
- It will return numeric results only - text is evaluated as Zero

Comment: I tested using full columns (e.g., `A:A`) with Excel 2010, and it works ok.

Comment: ok... I'll change that to recommend, as a fixed row count is (usually) faster than an open row count, which could conceivably check 1e6+ rows

Comment: how can we match from three columns if i have to compare values from three columns like less then equql to "<=". i am struggling in this condition.

Comment: A robust version that also copes with text is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21738182/2707864).

Answer (score 1):

Although I believe @MakeCents comment / suggestion on how to do this is the way I would go since it is the simplest, you could accomplish this a different way (MUCH more processor-intensive, though) using the `Index()` and `Match()` functions and Array formulas.

For example, suppose your 3 columns of data you're looking to match against are columns A-C and you're looking to return the matching value from column D in Sheet1

Now, the 3 values you're looking to have matched are in cells A1, B1 & C1 of Sheet2, you could use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!A:A=A1)*(Sheet1!B:B=B1)*(Sheet1!C:C=C1),0))
```

And **ENTER IT AS AN ARRAY FORMULA** by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a **Lookup with multiple criteria**.

**One of the most robust options** is

```
=INDEX(D:D,SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="d"),--(B:B="S"),--(C:C="Apr"),ROW(D:D)),0)
```

**It does not need to be entered as an array formula**.
Taken from [[1] (blogs.office.com)](http://blogs.office.com/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas/).

See also [this very complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21582535/2707864), which summarizes this and other options for performing a *lookup with multiple criteria*.

PS1: Note that I used references to full columns, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359430/returning-a-value-if-three-columns-match-in-excel#comment32876633_18360162).

PS2: This can be considered an enhancement to [the solution by Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360162/2707864) for the case when the output column does not contain numbers.

*References*

[1] This post is written by JP Pinto, the winner of the Great White Shark Award given for the best article written about VLOOKUP during VLOOKUP Week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF(A4=Data!$A$4:$A$741,IF(B4=Data!$B$4:$B$741,"Hai"))
```

Comment: please add some explanations how this answer be a solution to the OP's question

Comment: This may well solve the problem, but there are lots of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from you if only you explain how/why this solution solves the problem. Please edit your answer and add a bit of explanation.