# Comparing two columns in one Excel sheet, to two columns in another sheet, and if they match, copy data from another column

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking at using the Excel VLOOKUP function to accomplish this, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with it.

I need to do the following:

On sheet one, column A and column B contain 3000 rows of first names and last names.

I need to compare this to a second sheet that also has first names and last names, with a third column containing email addresses.

If the two columns are an exact match on sheet 1 and sheet 2(e.g. A1+B1 = Sheet2 A7+B7), I need to copy the email address from column C on sheet 2, to column C on sheet 1.

Is there a VLOOKUP formula to accomplish this, or is this going to need to be a VBA script?

Comment: I would do it by 1) Adding an extra column to each sheet that combines the names, and 2) Using a VLOOKUP with the new columns.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Put this formula on sheet1 column C:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(A1,B1),Sheet2!A:D,4,0)
```

You would need to have 4 columns on sheet2, the first column would need to be a CONCATENATE FORMULA like this:

```
=CONCAT(B1,C1)
```

The second column would be your first name, third column your last name and last column the corresponding email.

How this formula work's?

```
 =VLOOKUP(**CONCAT(A1,B1)**,Sheet2!A:D,4,0)
```

It's concatenating the first and last name on sheet1 and looking for it on Sheet2 on column A, if there's a match  it will return the email cell value in sheet2 column D (column D index is 4).

Hope this help you

Comment: A robust solution with no extra columns is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a VBA script that uses an SQL query, maybe something like this (*you need some SQL language skills in order to get the right result*). Anyways, this is the approach I would recommend for an advanced user:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset

sWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & 
sWorkbookName & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1"""

sSheet1="myDataSheet1"
sSheet2="myDataSheet2"
oConn.Open connString
'just an example of SQL, you have to customize it
sSQL = "SELECT [FIRST NAME], [LAST NAME],[EMAIL] FROM [" & sSheet2 & "$] " & 
" WHERE 
[FIRST NAME] + [LAST NAME} IN (SELECT [FIRST NAME] + [LAST NAME] FROM [" & sSheet1 & "$]" & ")  ORDER BY [FIRST NAME] ASC"

rs.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

'dump results on a temporary sheet 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tmp_sheet").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
oConn.Close
```

Comment: I don't think the questioner has any data in a SQL database.

Comment: Please be aware that you CAN RUN SQL QUERIES against an Excel table, in Excel VBA. Just need to add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library. But this is only for advanced users however, that also know SQL language

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter in `Sheet1!C1`

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!A:A=A1),--(Sheet2!B:B=B1),ROW(Sheet2!C:C)),0)
```

and then copy downwards.

This does not require:

1. Using VBA
2. Using array formulas
3. Using an additional (helper) column.

The importance of this is out of scope here.

#### **More details**

What you are looking for is typically called *Multiple Lookup*.
There are quite a few questions about it in SO, and many other articles elsewhere.
**I have compiled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576595/searching-an-excel-with-two-search-words-multiple-lookup-using-vba-macro) a list of such posts.**

There are many possible solutions for that.
The one I found most robust is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21738182/2707864).
This is what I used in the present answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1.A1=Sheet2.A1, Sheet1.B1=Sheet2.B1),Sheet2.C1,'')
```

Save this as formula to the Column C of the target sheet.

Comment: This looks good if the names are exactly the same on both sheets. They have to be matched up in same rows too.